# Getting unique values from column in a csv file

Tags: shell, csv, awk, uniq

I have the following input:

```
no,zadrar,MENTOR,rossana@xt.com,AGRATE
no,mittalsu,MENTOR,rossana@xt.com,GREATER NOIDA
no,abousamr,CADENCE,selim@xt.com,CROLLES
no,lokinsks,MENTOR,sergey@xt.com,CROLLES
no,billys,MENTOR,billy@xt.com,CROLLES
no,basiles1,CADENCE,stephane@xt.com,CASTELLETTO
no,cesaris1,CADENCE,stephane@xt.com,CROLLES
```

I want to get only the lines where column 4 is unique:

```
no,abousamr,CADENCE,selim@xt.com,CROLLES
no,lokinsks,MENTOR,sergey@xt.com,CROLLES
no,billys,MENTOR,billy@xt.com,CROLLES
```

I tried with:

```
awk -F"," '{print $4}' $vendor.csv | sort | uniq -u
```

But I get:

```
    selim@xt.com
    sergey@xt.com
    billy@xt.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(reading Input_file 2 times).

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{a[$4]++;next} a[$4]==1'  Input_file Input_file
```

Comment: Very nice, could you explain more why the input 2 times?

Comment: @nbari, 2 times I read first time it will take the count of lines and store them in array and second time to execute the condition if a count is `1` it should print line then only.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 This seems to be the best  solution I go for, thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can use simply the options provided by the `sort` command:

```
sort -u -t, -k4,4 file.csv
```

As you can see in the `man` page, option `-u` stands for "unique", `-t` for the field delimiter, and `-k` allows you to select the location (key).

Comment: no, OP wants only unique line.. in other words, any 4th column value which is present more than once should not be in output.. for ex: `rossana` is there twice, should not be in output but your solution will give one of them in output

Comment: You are right, better to remove the `cut` output to avoid confusion.

Comment: your answer is still wrong, not sure if you got what I wanted to convey

Comment: your answer give one of multiple value from column 4